# PHP SQL JAVASCRIPT SEARCH NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am working on a company website where a search bar is used to search the database of customers and employees by there name.

I have the output of the below code ([output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XNw6.png))
but it only searches the firstname and last name individually like this in the output ([output 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7mVd.png))i want to make it join together for searching both firstname and lastname.
I want to make a search like this ([output 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWuSj.png))

I have this code so far...

index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>INDEX PAGE</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container all">
   <br />
   <h2 align="center">COMPANY NAME</h2><br />

   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Customer Details" class="form-control" />
    </div>
   </div>

   <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  });
 }
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search.length>=2){

  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
}
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }

 });
});
</script>
```

and 2nd file..

fetch.php

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "users_db")or die("ERROR");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM users_users 
  WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR lastname LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  AND lastname LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR link LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
}
else
{

}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="otp">
  </div>
 ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <div class="oup">
   <a href="
   '.$row["link"].'
   ">
   '.$row["firstname"].'
   '.$row["lastname"].'
   </a>
   </div>
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo '';
}

?>
```

the above code has this output...(output 1)

[output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XNw6.png)

and after typing the firstname when i press spacebar it blanksout like in (output 2)

[output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7mVd.png)

i want to make the search continue after typing the firstname with spacebar in between..

something like this.. in the (output 3)

[output 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWuSj.png)

i am new at php javascript and sql so try to break it down for me.
thank you in advance.
can you guys give me some more tricks how to optimise more of this code.

Comment: why downvote? can you explain or leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Before i give my answer, I should say your code is open to SQL Injection. You should learn about [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to solve this security issue.

Now to answer your question. For searching both firstname and lastname you should separate search term before searching. Something like this:

```
      // --- Separate the search items
      if ( !empty($search) ){

        $searchWords = explode(' ', $search);
        $searchTerms = array();
        foreach ($searchWords as $word) {
            $word = trim($word);
            if (!empty($word)) {
                $searchTerms[] = "(firstname LIKE '%$word%' OR lastname LIKE '%$word%')";
            }
        }

      }

      // --- Search each search items
      $query = "SELECT * FROM users_users WHERE".implode(' AND ', $searchTerms);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE users_users ADD FULLTEXT(firstname, lastname, link);

$searchTerm = '+'.str_replace(' ','+',$search).'*';
$query = "SELECT * FROM users where MATCH(`firstname`,`lastname`,`link`) AGAINST (".searchTerm." IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```